# ArgumentOutOfRange Error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a file copy program with progressbar but It crashes at percentage computing.Here is my code:

```
private void operation()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        using (streamSFD)
        {
            using (Stream streamOFD = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open))
            {
                while (streamOFD.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                {
                    streamSFD.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    progressBar1.Value = percentage((int)streamOFD.Length, (int)streamSFD.Length);
                    label2.Text = streamSFD.Length.ToString() + "/" + streamOFD.Length.ToString();
                    label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private int percentage(int x, int y)
    {
        return (y * 100) / x;
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated problem: You're writing too much.  You need to write only the length returned from `Read()`.

Comment: progressBar1.Value = percentage((int)streamOFD.Length, (int)streamSFD.Length);

This part gives the exception.

Comment: Could you not just spend a minute of time for checking the documentation of [ProgressBar.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value.aspx) about the reasons/conditions when it would throw an http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value.aspx?

Comment: The value returned is -30.This is the reason but why would it return -30?

Comment: I see. This can only happen if one of your streams is longer than *int.MaxValue*. Note that *Stream.Length* is a **long** value. For example, 0x01FFFF0000 is a positive long value. Truncating it to an **int** will result in 0xFFFF0000 - which is a negative int...

Comment: So I should not use stream's length.Let me try it :)

Comment: No, you should have a function like `private int percentage(long x, long y)`. Inside, assign the result of the calculation to a long variable. Then return `Math.Min(longResult, (long) int.MaxValue)`. (I'll write an answer...)

Comment: private double percentage(long x, long y)
        {
            return (y * 100) / x;
        }

This works now ^^

Comment: Note, that as long as the result of your computation stays below **int.MaxValue** it will work. Most probably it will. However, in the rare case that the *double* will exceed int.MaxValue, you will essentially again feed a negative value into the progressbar. But then again, the progressbar will most likely already respond with an ArgumentOutOfRange anyway before your percentage value comes even close to int.MaxValue :)

Comment: why would it give any exception now ? It will always be between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments to the question it became clear, that the *percentage* method returned negative values. How can this happen?

Note that the property [Stream.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length.aspx) is a **long**, and so is [Stream.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx) (which is perhaps also a property you want to use for calculating the progress percentage).

Casting a *long* (width of 64 bit) to an *int* (width of 32 bit) will truncate the *long* by just taking the lower 32 bits into account.

Imagine you have the following positive *long* value:

```
0x1FFFFFF00 (hex) = 8589934336 (decimal)
```

Casting this to *int* will discard the upper 32 bits, resulting in:

```
0xFFFFFF00 (hex) = -256 (decimal)
```

(In most CPU/ALU architectures, negative integer numbers are commonly represented by the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of their absolute value.)

The key to fix the problem is to not truncate the long values. Since the resulting percentage value should be an *int* value in the range of 0...100 (it is a percentage for a progress bar), [Math.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h66z94h1.aspx) will be utilized to cap any calculation results greater than 100 (although, for the cod given in the question the calculation result should not exceed 100).

```
private int percentage(long x, long y)
{
    return (int) Math.Min( (y * 100) / x, 100L );
}
```

Now, casting *Stream.Length* to an *int* is not necessary anymore:

```
progressBar1.Value = percentage(streamOFD.Length, streamSFD.Length);
```